# How to correctly refresh the ribbon's MFC default recent documents list?

Tags: c++, mfc, ribbon, recent-file-list

How to correctly refresh the ribbon's MFC default recent documents list?

The list in not updating correclty.
I enabled it using this:
In the ribbon XML, inside the CATEGORY_MAIN tag i've created this

```
  <RECENT_FILE_LIST>
    <ENABLE>TRUE</ENABLE>
    <LABEL>Recent Documents</LABEL>
  </RECENT_FILE_LIST>
```

and in the ::InitInstance() of my derived CWinApp class i used

```
    LoadStdProfileSettings();
```

the problem is: When i open or save a file, the list isn't updated. But when i close and open the program it passes trought the "LoadStdProfileSettings()" and the list is updated.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.

in my derived CWinApp class, in the overwritten method AddToRecentFileList, i needed to read the recent file list again adding this at the end of the method:

```
m_pRecentFileList->ReadList();
```